# bash: ./run: No such file or directory

Tags: python, shell, docker

Im new to docker.
I am starting the `run` command with a script called `r`, which has the following code

```
proxy="--build-arg http_proxy=http://wwwcache.open.ac.uk:80 --build-arg https_proxy=http://wwwcache.open.ac.uk:80"
if [ "$http_proxy" == "" ]; then
 proxy=
fi
docker build $proxy -t bi-tbcnn docker
docker run -v $(pwd):/e -w /e --entrypoint bash --rm -it bi-tbcnn -c ./run
```

When I execute `r` I am getting the following error

```
bash: ./run: No such file or directory
```

but when I directly execute the ./run command on my terminal is ok

I use Docker Toolbox on windows

The project address is https://github.com/bdqnghi/bi-tbcnn

thanks

Comment: Maybe [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/133389/no-such-file-or-directory-but-the-file-exists) where the guy have the same trouble can be helpful :)

Comment: run need to be inside the docker container image

Comment: If you dont delete the contairen after running it (remove the  --rm flag) and you run docker exec to enter the machine, what happens if you run `bash ./run`?

Comment: As an aside, `if [ "$http_proxy" == "" ]` is undefined in POSIX shell, so you should replace it with `if [ "$http_proxy" = "" ]`, or slightly better `if [ -z "$http_proxy" ]`

Comment: And don't forget to include a [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) at the beginning of your shell scripts, e.g. `#!/bin/bash`

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue on docker for windows
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/stevelasker/2016/09/22/running-scripts-in-a-docker-container-from-windows-cr-or-crlf/

it seems you're facing an issue with Carriage Return(CR) and Line Feeds(LF) characters, maybe your code editor is changing the newline format automatically

can you to try open a bash session on the container and execute the script manually?

```
docker run -v $(pwd):/e -w /e --entrypoint bash --rm -it bi-tbcnn
root@a83fcd779f8e:/e# ./run
```

Please paste the output here

Comment: Thank you for your answer.This is my output. 
```docker run -v $(pwd):/e -w /e --entrypoint bash --rm -it bi-tbcnn```
```bash-4.4# ./run``` 
```bash: ./run: No such file or directory```
It seems useless